# Using $match and $unwind to get a count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning MongoDB aggregation pipeline, i tried to get matched count from output of `$unwind` and `$group`. I am able to see the results for `$unwind` and `$group`. But I am not sure why I didn't get the matched count. Please help to get percentage field greater than 25.

Here's an example document:

```
{  
    "_id":ObjectId("599e9dbd8fbad926e712f902"),
    "sample":"1",
    "attribute":[  
        {  
            "functionName":"1",
            "percentage":31.6
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this:

```
db.docs3.aggregate({  
    $unwind:'$attribute'
},
{  
    $group:{  
        _id:{  
            func:"$attribute.functionName",
            percen:"$attribute.percentage"
        }
    }
})
```

And got this output:

```
{ "_id" : { "func" : "7", "percen" : 30 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "5", "percen" : 23.1 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "8", "percen" : 27.8 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "6", "percen" : 32.1 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "1", "percen" : 31.6 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "2", "percen" : 35 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "3", "percen" : 7.1 } }
{ "_id" : { "func" : "4", "percen" : 31.6 } }
```

I tried this:

```
db.docs3.aggregate({  
    $unwind:'$attribute'
},
{  
    $group:{  
        _id:{  
            func:"$attribute.functionName",
            percen:"$attribute.percentage"
        }
    }
},
{  
    $match:{  
        "attribute.percentage":{  
            $gt:25
        }
    }
})
```

And I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want a count of

1. Documents having at least one attribute with `percentage > 25`

Or

2. Attributes having `percentage > 25`

If you are interested in No. 1 then you do not need to unwind the `attribute` array in order to apply your match. The following will return a count of documents containing at least one attribute with `percentage > 25`:

```
db.getCollection('other').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'attribute.percentage': { $gt: 25 } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

If you are interested in No. 2 then the following will return a count of attributes with `percentage > 25`:

```
db.getCollection('other').aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$attribute' },
    { $match: { 'attribute.percentage': { $gt: 25 } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

For the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599e9dbd8fbad926e712f902"),
    "sample" : "1",
    "attribute" : [ 
        {
            "functionName" : "1",
            "percentage" : 31.6
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a54104e7e9cc2109863beb"),
    "sample" : "1",
    "attribute" : [ 
        {
            "functionName" : "2",
            "percentage" : 21.2
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a542c4e7e9cc2109863c45"),
    "sample" : "1",
    "attribute" : [ 
        {
            "functionName" : "2",
            "percentage" : 20.2
        }, 
        {
            "functionName" : "2",
            "percentage" : 28.2
        }, 
        {
            "functionName" : "2",
            "percentage" : 35.2
        }
    ]
}
```

The first command returns `count=2`, the second command returns `count=3`.

Comment: Hi glitch, Thanks for your reply. Actually i am trying to get list of functionName having > 25 percentage.

Comment: @ManiMuthu.K could you please update the question to include an example document which shows the output you want? This is the clearest way of expressing your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the money sign to get the current value, and use the same field name you used in your $group stage

```
db.docs3.aggregate({
    $unwind:'$attribute'
},
{  
    $group:{  
        _id:{  
            func:"$attribute.functionName",
            percen:"$attribute.percentage"
        }
    }
},
{  
    $match:{  
        "$_id.percen":{  
            $gt:25
        }
    }
})
```